# What is the word for : "A person who, in general, does not agree with the general/popular opinion"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that I am that person :D 
With all seriousness, I am pretty sure there is a word for it, and I have seen it, but i forgot it.

Comment: You're a damn dirty ***contrarian***. Go ahead, tell me you don't agree. ;) You probably think you're a cool ***rebel*** or ***nonconformist***, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Try **iconoclastic**

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iconoclastic)

> a person who criticizes or opposes beliefs and practices that are widely accepted.

Comment: Or an iconoclast perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

**Heretic**. It more or less means just that.

Merriam Webster describes it as:

> One who dissents from an accepted belief or doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

A ***maverick***, perhaps - An unorthodox or independent-minded person; a person who refuses to conform to the views of a particular group or party; an individualist (OED).